# Beginner's confusion about POST method in REST service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I went to a open lecture about **Jersey REST web service** and made some notes. Here is what the lecturer said in the lecture, I am quite confuse about it.

> i.you will need POST some content to /files/. For example, you
>   have a file locally called data.json.Posting the content of that file
>   to your REST service will store the content on the server with a name
>   it chooses automatically, say 3.json, in a folder chosen by you.
>
> ii.The key thing here is the REST service will need to manage the
>   files it creates by choosing a name that hasn't been used and return
>   that name to sender, so the sender can re-download the content it sent
>   using the name it gets.( The sender do not know which name the content
>   will be given until it receives the response from the REST service).

For step i, is that means upload a file to the service and save to a new location? What is mean by the service will give it a name automatically?

For step ii, is that means if I send three files into the service, when I call GET /files/1, GET /files/2 and GET /files/3 will return the content of 1.json, 2.json, 3.json respectively? Besides the lecturer said we can use curl command line to post a file to the service.

The lecturer did not provide any example, which made me not understant it clearly.

Is it possible to help me to write a demo about that or provide some examples to me?

Comment: Please, **do not** vandalize your question after it has been answered. If you really dont want it to stay here, you can ask for deletion.

Comment: You should accept answers, not deface them

Answer (score 1):

> you have a file locally called `data.json`

Alright, simple enough

> Posting the content of that file to your REST service will store the content on the server

Sure, saving files. It reads that POST data, and stores it to disk.

> a name it chooses automatically

This is a minor detail... It could be stored as the same name, but then you'd have conflicting filenames.

> in a folder chosen by you

That point isn't really clear... but, moving on.

> the REST service will need to manage the files it creates by choosing a name that hasn't been used

Exactly the earlier point.

> and return that [...] to sender

Think about a typical website... You request `http://stackoverflow.com`. It **returns** back HTML. Your REST service is just returning a string / file.

> return that **name** to sender, so the sender can re-download the content it sent using the **name it gets**.( The sender **do not know which name the content will be given** until it receives the response from the REST service).

The client needs to know the **name of the file** that was added. Otherwise, you don't know how to request the file; the server had generated its own name for the file you sent to it originally.

---

> if I send three files into the service, when I call GET /files/1, GET /files/2 and GET /files/3 will return the content of 1.json, 2.json, 3.json respectively?

Not quite - The server generated the names of the files. So, a better example would be

```
POST -d file.json /files
```

Outputs the text

```
20160801-21-38.json
```

And in order to request that file back, you now need to use that value

```
GET /files/20160801-21-38.json
```

Comment: That's roughly the syntax of a cURL request. Personally, I test my REST services with the Postman tool. Simply put; you just make a POST request like any other network request. But it has additional data going along with that request. Then you read the server's response... Save that off to some variable for later retrieving. When you want the file, you use a GET request to "get it". The code isn't so important; once you understand the concepts, you should be able to pick up any networking library and perform these tasks